# Run bash script with command line arguments

Tags: bash, unix-shell

I want to do

```
/usr/bin/bash myscript.sh -args
```

which, as it stands, runs the script but doesn't pass the args to it. I realize that the conventional syntax is simply

```
./myscript.sh -args
```

but I'm curious as to what I need to do in order to call the script from `bash` explicitly.

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps if you showed your script we'd be better able to diagnose the problem. Also, what version of Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the script in debug output mode

```
/usr/bin/bash --verbose myscript.sh -args
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide information about your operating system.  Having 'bash' located at "/usr/bin/bash" tips me off that you're probably not running one of the more common GNU/Linux distributions.

On that note, what does the she-bang of the script look like?  If it's any different from the following, then you're not doing the equivalent with your bash command:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

One other suggestion I can pull out of the blue is to try escaping the parameters to bash, just in case there's some strange getopt thing going on.

```
/usr/bin/bash -- myscript.sh -args
```

Comment: And change permission so the file can be executed:

chmod a+x file (or u+x if you want make it executable only to the user)